# What does "buffer size" mean when streaming text to a file

Tags: .net, buffer

I'm working with the [StreamWriter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0wf7ab94(v=vs.100).aspx) class in .NET to output a lot of text to a large file.

What does buffer size mean, and how does it effect speed and performance when writing text out to a file?

Surprisingly, I could not find the answer with a simple Google search.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Writing to a file requires using the [WriteFile()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365747%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) winapi function.  Note the function signature, the 2nd argument is lpBuffer, a buffer that contains the bytes that need to be written.  The 3rd argument say how many bytes are in that buffer.

You can technically write just a single byte at a time.  But that's inefficient, WriteFile() is not a very cheap function.  It works much better if you write a chunk of bytes instead.  There will be many fewer calls to WriteFile.

So StreamWriter has a byte[] array that acts as the buffer.  When you call Write/Line() then it converts the text to bytes and copies them into that buffer.  Very fast.

Which works until that array is full.  Then it *must* call WriteFile() to empty the buffer again.  How often that happens entirely depends on the size of the buffer and how much text you write.

StreamWriter can write to many different kind of streams.  It doesn't have to be just a file on disk.  You can also use it to write text to a network stream for example.  Or the screen.  Or through a pipe to another process.  Or to a device through a serial or USB port.  Or memory through a memory-mapped file.  Etcetera, many possibilities.

Clearly very different things happen under the hood when you make the Write/Line() call.  You *may* make your program work more optimally if you use a different size buffer.  Above all, the Microsoft programmers just could not predict how you are going to use StreamWriter.  And could therefore not know what buffer size is "best".  They did not want to paint you into a corner where you always had to live with the buffer size that they chose.

So you got the option to pick another size.  The default one is 1024 bytes.  That a pretty modest size, based on the assumption that you'll write to another stream that's also buffered.  Like FileStream, the one you'll use when you write to a file.  It has a buffer of 4096 bytes.

If you want to *know* which buffer size is best then you have to experiment.  It cannot be predicted, there's entirely too much code that runs under the hood to allow you to guess at it.  But beware that by far the most common outcome of such a test is that it just doesn't have a noticeable effect.  Which is the way it should be, it is an operating system's duty to perform well under all reasonable circumstances.  When an oddball driver is involved then you'd have a good reason to give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

Buffer size refers to the number of characters to save in memory before writing to the file.  This process is called `buffering`.  The underlying assumption is that a write to a file is much more slower that writing to memory.

See Wikipedia for a good [definition of data buffer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_buffer).